# Navigate to the same component after the session expire

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a token based API where a session is valid for 10 mins if the user is idle for more than 10 mins token will be changed and error response will be received from the API where the user will be redirected to the login page.

Currently if the user login again it redirects to the main page, but my requirement is the user should be able to login to the same page where he left before.

can i use some sessions to store the value of the router where the user is active and after the session is terminated i can use the same session value and navigate to the same page where he left ?.

for a simulation i have created a application [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/route-session-angular?embed=1&file=src/app/user-component/user-component.component.ts) where i am using the setTimout function and navigating to login page after 10 seconds.

Suppose say the user clicks login it redirects to the user page and from there he navigates to dashboard component after 10 seconds it redirects to the login page if i click  login again it want to navigate to the same component where user left

**Login Page**

```
<div id="login">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="login-row" class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
                <div id="login-column" class="col-md-6">
                    <div id="login-box" class="col-md-12">
                        <form id="login-form" class="form" action="" method="post">
                            <h3 class="text-center text-info">Login</h3>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="username" class="text-info">Username:</label><br>
                                <input [(ngModel)]= "userName" type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="password" class="text-info">Password:</label><br>
                                <input [(ngModel)]= "password" type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="submit" (click)="formValidation()" name="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-md" value="submit">
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Login.component.ts**

```
formValidation(){
    console.log(this.userName);
    console.log(this.password);
    this.router.navigate(['user'])
  }
```

Suggest me the better way to handle the router navigation after the session is terminated.
Link to edit [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/route-session-angular?embed=1&file=src/app/login/login.component.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm doing it like this. When the error response is received from api i redirect the user to login page with
this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: **state**.url }});

("**state**" is RouterStateSnapshot from @angular/router)

and on the login page i get the return url from query with:

this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'];

("**route**" is ActivatedRoute from @angular/router)

and on successful login i redirect the user:
 this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);

("**router**" is Router from @angular/router)

Comment: Can u please update the code in stackblitz i have created a sample application here [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/route-session-angular?embed=1&file=src/app/login/login.component.ts)

Comment: Here you go [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/route-session-angular-atmm8q?file=src%2Fapp%2Fguard%2Fauth-guard.ts). I have added an authentication guard, in there you can check if the token is valid.

Comment: @Santhosh That's true. The only thing you can do is to put the page in a cookie or local storage when the token expires.